# Angles in Isosceles Triangles

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, triangles

Find the value of $x$ in the triangle.

[image]

My attempt,

I do know that because it is an isosceles triangle, so that $\angle ABC=\angle ACB$

Of course we can see that $y=3x$ and $z=5x$ so that $x=9$ by adding $12x+3x+5x=180$

But how do we know that that's the unique solution?

Basically we can see that $$5x+y=3x+z$$

But how to know $y=3x$ and $z=5x$ are the only possible solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you surmise, knowing that $5x+y=3x+z$ certainly doesn't tell you that $y=3x,z=5x$.  You could have $y=3x+a,z=5x+a$ for any $a>-3x$.

Comment: Does it mean that we could not find an unique answer for $x$?@lulu

Comment: Well, the equality of those two lower angles isn't all the information you have.

Comment: @lulu How to use the angle BAD?

Comment: Keep trying.  Write out all the equations the triangle implies.

Comment: hint: apply sine rules to triangle $ABD$ and $ACD$.

Comment: @lulu, I found that angle BAC=4x.  But could not proceed anymore

Comment: @achillehui Can you show me how? Thanks

Comment: Since $\angle BAC = 4x$, you can express $\angle ABD$ and $\angle ACD$ in terms of $x$. Since the triangle is isosceles $\frac{AB}{AD} = \frac{AC}{AD}$ will give you a trigonometric equation in $x$. On first glance, that equation looks ugly but you can simplify it using standard trigonometric identities. At the end, you will find $x$ is an integer (in degree).

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by expressing $\angle ABD$ and $\angle ACD$ in terms of $x$. I thought $\angle ABD=5x$ and $\angle ACD=3x$? @achillehui

Comment: oops, should be $\angle ADB$ and $\angle ADC$.

Comment: @achillehui I know that $\angle ABD=180-8x$ and $\angle ADC=180-4x$. But how do I form an equation to solve $x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this problem is more of a trigonometric equation than a geometry problem. However, by the law of sine, we conclude:

$$\frac {\sin 5x}{\sin 8x}=\frac{AD}{AB}=\frac{AD}{AC}=\frac {\sin 3x}{\sin \angle ADC}=\frac {\sin 3x}{\sin 4x}\implies \sin 8x \sin 3x=\sin 5x \sin 4x$$
$$\implies 2\cos 4x\sin 3x=\sin 5x\implies -\sin x+\sin 7x=\sin 5x$$
$$-\sin x=\sin 5x-\sin 7x=-2\cos 6x\sin x\implies 2\cos 6x=1 \implies x=10^{\circ}.$$

Comment: How to get sin8x?

Comment: @user219126 $\angle ADB =180^{\circ}-8x$ and $\sin (180^{\circ}-x)=\sin x$

Answer (score 5):

[image]

In the figure, $E$ is a point on $CD$ produced such that $\angle CAE=5x$.

$\because  \angle ACE=\angle BAD=3x$, $\angle EAC=\angle DBA=5x$ and $AC=AB$

$\therefore \Delta ACE \cong \Delta BAD $ (ASA)

$\therefore BD=AE$  ----- (1)

$\because \angle EAD=\angle EDA=4x$

$\therefore AE=DE$ ----- (2)

From (1), (2), we have $DE=BD$ and hence $\angle DEB=\angle DBE$

Since $\angle DEB+\angle DBE=12x$

$\therefore \angle DEB=\angle DBE=6x$

This implies that $\angle EBA=6x-5x=x$

$\because \angle EBA=\angle EAB=x$

$\therefore EA=EB$ ----- (3)

(1), (2) and (3) implies that $EB=BD=DE$

$\Delta BED$ is an equilateral triangle.

Hence $\angle BED=60^o$

$6x=60^o$

$x=10^o$

Comment: There should be a purely geometric approach. Will work on it.

Comment: Hope to see the geometric approach. Thanks man!

Comment: This seems like a good, purely geometric approach.

Comment: @ Edward Porcella Thanks for the editing. I am too absent-minded